# print all duplicates in not well formatted csv

Tags: csv, awk

I have a huge csv file (~17GB) and I need to create new file that contains all rows that the value of the last column appear more than once, unfortunately, the file is not well formatted. There are values that contains commas, like line 6 in the below example:

```
entity,entity_type,component_id
bla@gmail.com,email,1111
lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
15158112233,phone,3333
15158990000,phone,2222
hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
1327168,phone,4444
fds_213445,device,3333
```

for the following example I would expect this new file:

```
lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
15158990000,phone,2222
15158112233,phone,3333
hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
fds_213445,device,3333
```

I currently use a naive solution of:

1. Count the size of each component and store in file A.
2. Remove from file A all components with size = 1.
3. Running in a script over all component_ids in file A print the match lines from the original file to new result file.

But, as I said, this solution is very naive and it's running for a very long time (almost a week and still running...)

How could I create new file contains all lines with component_id appear more than once in bash, and in efficient way?

Comment: On SO its highly encouraged for users to add their efforts in their questions, so please do add your efforts in your question, thank you.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, I added the effort, as you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` and two passes through the file? First one counts the occurrences of the last field, second one prints just the duplicates.

```sh
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { ids[$NF]++; next }
         ids[$NF] > 1 || FNR == 1' hugefile.csv hugefile.csv > newfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Using single time reading Input_file and playing around with arrays to check if last field value is more than 1 in whole Input_file.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
{
  arr[$NF]++
  if(!temparr[$NF]++){
    first[$NF]=$0
  }
}
arr[$NF]>1{
  if(first[$NF]){
    print first[$NF]
    delete first[$NF]
  }
  print
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Reading whole Input_file and getting all lines and last fields values into arrays and playing around with them in `END` block of the `awk` once Input_file is done reading.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
{
  arr[$NF]++
  if(!arr1[$NF]++){
    arr2[++count]=$NF
  }
  val[$NF]=(val[$NF]?val[$NF] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(arr[arr2[i]]>1){
      print val[arr2[i]]
    }
  }
}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** My 3rd solution was to pass Input_file 2 times into `awk` which is already covered by Shawn in his answer :) so removed it from here. Also these are tested with shown samples and NOT with huge data set fyi here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this without reading the whole file into memory at once in awk while being able to handle input coming from a pipe or a file (so it'd work even if the input was the output of some other command without creating a temp file to contain all of the input) and retaining the original input order and header.

Input from a file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print (NR>1), $NF, ++cnt[$NF], NR, $0}' file |
    sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3nr |
    awk -F, '$2!=p2{p2=$2; p3=$3} (NR==1) || (p3>1)' |
    sort -t, -k4,4n |
    cut -d, -f5-
entity,entity_type,component_id
lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
15158112233,phone,3333
15158990000,phone,2222
hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
fds_213445,device,3333
```

or input from a pipe:

```
$ cat file |
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print (NR>1), $NF, ++cnt[$NF], NR, $0}' |
    sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3nr |
    awk -F, '$2!=p2{p2=$2; p3=$3} (NR==1) || (p3>1)' |
    sort -t, -k4,4n |
    cut -d, -f5-
entity,entity_type,component_id
lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
15158112233,phone,3333
15158990000,phone,2222
hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
fds_213445,device,3333
```

Note that this approach allows you to take input from a pipe, not just from a file, so you can pipe the output of another command to it if you like. In the above only `sort` has to handle the whole input at once and it's designed to do so by using demand paging, etc. so it's extremely unlikely to have any issues handling large input.

Here's what the script is doing in steps so you can see how it works:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print (NR>1), $NF, ++cnt[$NF], NR, $0}' file
0,component_id,1,1,entity,entity_type,component_id
1,1111,1,2,bla@gmail.com,email,1111
1,2222,1,3,lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
1,3333,1,4,15158112233,phone,3333
1,2222,2,5,15158990000,phone,2222
1,3333,2,6,hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
1,4444,1,7,1327168,phone,4444
1,3333,3,8,fds_213445,device,3333
```

```
$ ... | sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3nr
0,component_id,1,1,entity,entity_type,component_id
1,1111,1,2,bla@gmail.com,email,1111
1,2222,2,5,15158990000,phone,2222
1,2222,1,3,lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
1,3333,3,8,fds_213445,device,3333
1,3333,2,6,hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
1,3333,1,4,15158112233,phone,3333
1,4444,1,7,1327168,phone,4444
```

```
$ ... | awk -F, '$2!=p2{p2=$2; p3=$3} (NR==1) || (p3>1)'
0,component_id,1,1,entity,entity_type,component_id
1,2222,2,5,15158990000,phone,2222
1,2222,1,3,lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
1,3333,3,8,fds_213445,device,3333
1,3333,2,6,hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
1,3333,1,4,15158112233,phone,3333
```

```
$ ... | sort -t, -k4,4n
0,component_id,1,1,entity,entity_type,component_id
1,2222,1,3,lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
1,3333,1,4,15158112233,phone,3333
1,2222,2,5,15158990000,phone,2222
1,3333,2,6,hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
1,3333,3,8,fds_213445,device,3333
```

```
$ ... | cut -d, -f5-
entity,entity_type,component_id
lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
15158112233,phone,3333
15158990000,phone,2222
hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
fds_213445,device,3333
```

Comment: Don't the `sorts` each require everything in memory?

Comment: @keithpjolley no, that's what I mentioned in the text - `...only sort has to handle the whole input at once and it's designed to do so by using demand paging, etc....` so it doesn't have to store it in memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "bash" solution. bash isn't the right tool for this kind of task - not to say that someone won't come up with an elegant all bash solution...  Anyways, since `awk` answers have already appeared I figured I'd try a python solution.  This slurps the entire file into memory but most machines in 2020 should handle a 17GB file just fine. This does one pass on the file read.

```
python3 -c "import csv,collections;d=collections.defaultdict(list);[d[r[-1]].append(r) for r in csv.reader(open('hugefile.csv'))];[print(','.join(r)) for (k,v) in d.items() for r in v if len(v)>1]"
```

Broken down:

```
import csv,collections

#Create a defaultdict that accepts lists:
d=collections.defaultdict(list)

# For each row in the csv file append the row to the dict with
# the last field (id) as the key:
[d[r[-1]].append(r) for r in csv.reader(open('hugefile.csv'))]

# Print each value in the dict if value if the value has more than one row in it.
[print(','.join(r)) for (k,v) in d.items() for r in v if len(v)>1]
```

Output with your example data:

```
lalal@hotmail.com,email,2222
15158990000,phone,2222
15158112233,phone,3333
hello,world@gmail.com,email,3333
fds_213445,device,3333
```